# ng-repeat doesn't trigger $destroy on specific element

Tags: angularjs

I have created a directive and using inside ng-repeat. I am using remove button also to remove specific element from the list. The issue is, whenever I remove specific element from list, it always trigger $destroy in my directive on the last element in the list instead of specific element.

For example, I have 4 elements in the list like [1,2,3,4]. My directive displays 2 text boxes. I uses ng-repeat to iterate over list and display directive with 2 textboxes and remove button in every row. Now I clicked the remove button on 2nd row, but it triggers the $destroy on 4th element in my directive instead of 2nd.

Any idea how to fix this, to trigger the $destroy on specific element only.

Comment: Can you show the code/fiddle plz?

Answer (score 0):

It's due to track by $index, in which case it will always remove the last row in the list.

Comment: track by `$index` doesn't imply that it will always remove the last element, but you never showed any code to demonstrate your usage of `$destroy`.  your implementation doesn't sound correct.